# Accessibility Event Issue

Tags: android, service, widget, accessibility

I want to make my own accessibility service using the API's, but when
some buttons are clicked, no event of type `VIEW_CLICKED` is logged.

In **accessibility.xml**, 
I set `android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews`

I'm not sure Why when I click the **Accept** and **Continue** button in Chrome (as part of the first run activity), no click event is logged.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `android:accessibilityEventTypes`. To intercept clicks you need to use `typeViewClicked` option.

Something like that:

```
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked"
```

For more information you can check [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html#attr_android:accessibilityEventTypes).